# how to get a different time-clock on CLI apart from your time-zone?

Tags: command-line, date, timezone

Is there a way to invoke or know a different clock or time on the CLI. The thing is I'm on UTC+5:30 time but at times need to know time in different time-zones. If there is a CLI way in which this can be known would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several others have mentioned, the `TZ` environment variable is what affects the output of `date`.  However, in most cases you won't want to *leave* `TZ` changed; you will just want to see the time in that timezone, leaving your environment unaffected afterwards.

For that purpose, the best tool to use is `env`.  From the `env` man page:

```
NAME
    env - run a program in a modified environment
SYNOPSIS
    env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
```

So in this case, the command you want would look something like:

```
env TZ='EST' date
```

There are other formats acceptable for the timezone—many of them.  If you have particular requirements, it's a good idea to read `man timezone` which explains the valid timezone formats.

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted with

`$ env TZ='UTC' date
Sun Oct 11 00:19:26 UTC 2015`

Comment: needed to understand how ` /usr/share/zoneinfo ` works  I tried UK/Great Britain as an e.g. and was surprised to note that it is only 1 hour after UTC/GMT .  `$ alias uk
alias uk='env TZ='\''Europe/London'\'' date' `

Comment: Actually, the single quotes are optional; `env TZ=EST date` works just as well, as does `env TZ=Europe/London date`.  So for a simpler alias (more readable) use `alias uk='env TZ=Europe/London date'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the timezone `date` will use by changing the variable `TZ`

For example

```
$ date
Sun Oct 11 01:42:44 CEST 2015
$ TZ=US/Pacific date                                
Sat Oct 10 16:43:14 PDT 2015
$ TZ=UTC date                                                      
Sat Oct 10 23:44:04 UTC 2015
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `man date` has your answer:

```
 ENVIRONMENT

 The following environment variables affect the execution of date:

 TZ      The timezone to use when displaying dates.  The normal format is a pathname
         relative to /usr/share/zoneinfo.  For example, the command
         ``TZ=America/Los_Angeles date'' displays the current time in California.  See
         environ(7) for more information.
```

`/usr/share/zoneinfo` has the Time Zone names.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that there are only a few TZ's that you frequently need to check.  With that assumption, you would probably find it useful to setup aliases or functions for each TZ you need to check.  An alias is as simple as...

```
alias est="TZ=US/Eastern date"
```

A function definition would look like...

```
est() { TZ=US/Eastern date ; }
```

Defining functions for each TZ would have the added benefit of isolating the change to the TZ.  Meaning that the value assigned to TZ would disappear when the function ends, returning to its original value when you are dropped back to your shell.

To make either of these available each time you login you'll need to include it in ~/.bash_profile.  Once you have one of these in place, open a new shell or logout/login, then get the date/time with `est`.